# Add multiple annotations with geocoder.geocodeAddressString (recursion?)

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm trying to add multiple annotations to my mapview, with the geocoders geocodeAddressString-function.

The problem is, it's only adding one of them, evn though it tells me that both are run..
Here's my code - and btw, i've never really used recursion before, so please correct me if i'm doing it all wrong! :)

```
func geoCode(addresses: [String]) {
    print("Addresser: \(addresses.count)")

    guard let address = addresses.first else {
        print("No more adresses :) - returning")
        return
    }
    print("3333 address: \(address)")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
            print("In geocoder!")
            if error == nil {
                if let placemark = (placemarks?[0])! as? CLPlacemark {
                    self.annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
                    self.map.addAnnotation(self.annotation)

                    let remainingAddresses = Array(addresses[1..<addresses.count])
                    print("addresses left: \(remainingAddresses.count)")
                    self.geoCode(remainingAddresses)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my console output:

```
Addresser: 2
3333 address: Kastrupvej 2A 2300 København s
In geocoder!
addresses left: 1
Addresser: 1
3333 address: Holmbladsgade 20 2300 København S
In geocoder!
addresses left: 0
Addresser: 0
No more adresses :) - returning
```

But there's only 1 annotation on my map, which is the last one.. 
Can anyone tell me why, and what I am doing wrong? :)
I tried with a for-loop first, but it seems that the geocoder only can handle 1 thing at at time - and thats why I tried with the async and recursion kind of approach.

Have a lovely day!

Answer (score 0):

- Try allocating geoCoder every time.
- Call geocoder.cancelGeocode() method.

Like this:

```
func geoCode(addresses: [String]) {
    print("Addresser: \(addresses.count)")

    guard let address = addresses.first else {
        print("No more adresses :) - returning")
        return
    }
    print("3333 address: \(address)")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
            print("In geocoder!")
            if error == nil {
                if let placemark = (placemarks?[0])! as? CLPlacemark {
                    self.annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
                    self.map.addAnnotation(self.annotation)

                    let remainingAddresses = Array(addresses[1..<addresses.count])
                    print("addresses left: \(remainingAddresses.count)")
                    self.geoCode(remainingAddresses)
                }
                geocoder.cancelGeocode()
            }
        }
    }

}
```